# DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED(0x80040E4D) C# can't open database more than once

Tags: c#, ms-access

ok, I've been struggling for so long. I can't access my database(Access) for a second time. Please help. The error is given in the Search() method

```
namespace OEFEN
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string DBFile;
    public OleDbConnection myDB;
    public string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=";
    public string searchString;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openDBToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DBFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void listToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDB = new OleDbConnection(conn+DBFile);
        myDB.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter myDB_Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Students ", myDB);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myDB_Adapter.Fill(ds, "Students");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember="Students";
        myDB.Close();
    }

    private void searchToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 iets = new Form3();

        iets.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        iets.Show();

    }

    public void Search()
    {

        myDB = new OleDbConnection(conn+DBFile);
        myDB.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter anderAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Students WHERE st_Surname=" + searchString, myDB);
        DataSet kk = new DataSet();
        anderAdapter.Fill(kk, "List");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = kk;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "List";
        myDB.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Need to see the call context, the code that is calling `Search()` which doesn't seem to be here.

Comment: It is the exception you get when DBFile was never assigned.  "Second time" tends to be caused by other code creating another instance of Form1 instead of using the one that the user is looking at.  Search your solution for "new Form1".  If you find it then you found the bug.

Comment: The database is still open when opened for the second time. It needs to be closed first. It is kept open because a reference is held in dataGridView1.DataSource.